# Get Embedded pdf File

Tags: c#, pdf, stream

I have looked through the forums and found many seemingly related questions, but nothing has helped thus far. I want to be able to get select pdfs from various websites. Here is a snippet that I'm using successfully for most of the documents I'm interested in.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filePaths[1]))
{
     var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(filePaths[1]);
     myRequest.Method = "GET";
     WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
     var sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
     var fileBytes = sr.ReadToEnd();
     using (var sw = new StreamWriter("<localfilepath/name")
          {
               sw.Write(fileBytes);
          }
}
```

The problem comes when I try to get this document: http://www.azdor.gov/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=r_I2VeNlcCQ%3d&tabid=265&mid=921

If I use the above code, I get a DotNetNuke error. I tried utilizing a WebClient as many other posts have suggested, but get the same error.

When I use this code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0";
request.ContentType = "application/x-unknown";
request.Method = "GET";
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
     using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
     {
          var sr2 = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);//.ASCII);
          var srt = sr2.ReadToEnd();
          var a = srt.Length;
          using (var sw = new StreamWriter("WebDataTestdocs/testpdf.pdf"))
          {
               sw.Write(srt);
          }
     }
}
```

I get a file back, but it says it was corrupted. Also utilizing UTF8 makes the file size bigger than the one I get when going to the site. If I make the Encoding.ASCII, the file size is correct, but still am getting the corrupted file error. I can see the English text in the file by opening it with notepad, so I'm not sure what is corrupted exactly.

Any help that can be offered would be greatly appreciated, I've been at this for quite a while!

Comment: You are using StreamReader, i.e. a class for reading text data, to read a PDF, i.e. binary data. This is almost sure to corrupt the data. I'm not knowledgeable in c#, though, and so don't know the classes to use.